# permission denied while deploying rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, capistrano

i'm getting permission denied while deploying using capistrano

Error:

```
DEBUG [0203645e] Command: ( GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/xxx/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git ls-remote git@github.com:yyy/xxx )
DEBUG [0203645e]    Permission denied (publickey).
DEBUG [0203645e]    
DEBUG [0203645e]    fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
DEBUG [0203645e]    
DEBUG [0203645e] Finished in 5.938 seconds with exit status 128 (failed).
```

My ssh key is available in server and git(same key available in both places

I was able to push previously
if more information needed please tell me.

Comment: Try with `ssh-add` in terminal before `git push`.

Comment: Hi Vucko, i'm getting this error while trying to deploy to server using capistrano and not git push

Comment: ssh-add before cap deploy worked out for me

Comment: If your issue has been solved, you should post an answer to your own question and accept it as the solution.

Comment: ssh-add is working fine for me, thanks Vucko